# How to filter specific key-value pair in hash that matches an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

My input is:

```
{"id"=>34, "fname"=>"XXX", "department"=>"IT", "email"=>"xxx@example.com"}

schema = [
  {:type=>"string", :name=>"email", :control_type=>"email", :label=>"EMAIL"},
  {:type=>"string", :name=>"fname", :control_type=>"text", :label=>"FNAME"},
  {:type=>"string", :name=>"surname", :control_type=>"text", :label=>"LNAME"}
]
```

How do I pick only:

```
{"fname"=>"XXX", "email"=>"xxx@example.com"}
```

matching the `:name` of `schema` array?

Comment: Would you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails provides a `Hash` method that makes filtering quite simple - [`slice()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice). In combination with the splat operator `*` you could write the following code.

```
fields = schema.map { |e| e[:name] }

input.slice(*fields)
#=> {"fname"=>"XXX", "email"=>"xxx@example.com"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first generate field names from `schema`

```
fields = schema.map{|f| f[:name]}
```

Then filter out your input:

```
input =  {"id"=>34, "fname"=>"XXX", "department"=>"IT", "email"=>"xxx@example.com"}

input.select{|k, v| fields.include?(k)}
#=>  {"fname"=>"XXX", "email"=>"xxx@example.com"}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried looping both schema and input but didn't get the desired result.